# Azure Functions/.NET7: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=7.0.0.0

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

Okay, so I've inherited a bunch of Azure functions running on deprecated packages. I've successfully updated most of them to .net7.0 but I'm currently getting stuck on this problem with **all** of them that are running Memory Cache. Building goes perfect. Startup not so much:

```
[2023-08-14T20:17:04.106Z] Error configuring services in an external startup class.
[2023-08-14T20:17:04.107Z] Error configuring services in an external startup class. SalesPart: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've tried all available versions of Microsoft.Extensions.Memory.Caching without any success. The error message containing "7.0.0.0" appear with the same version number even though I can't find any references to it in the project. I've cleared the .nuget folder of Memory.Caching packages multiple times as well. I'm running it all in Visual Studio 2022.

A sample of the package versioning found in the project file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.15" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I would be happy if someone could share some knowledge that might solve this issue. I've had no luck with SO and Google so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue you're running into is caused by an incomplete migration to `Azure Functions V4`. I'm assuming that your inherited functions were running `v3`.

If you look at Microsoft's documentation for `v3` to `v4` migrations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-isolated%2Cazure-cli%2Cwindows&pivots=programming-language-csharp) you'll see that your `.csproj` needs as few changes.

First of all, you're going to want to make sure to update **all** of your nuget packages to their latest versions, and then, you're going to want to make your `.csproj` look something like this:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.9" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" Version="3.0.15" />
  </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

To simplify, you're going to want to replace the: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions...` package with:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also, you're going to want to add `<Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>` in order to get everything working correctly using `.NET7` and Azure Functions `v4`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards something I never thought about. I needed to add the ExecutionContext described above, as well as the Program.cs file I captured from a new project in VS, containing the  HostBuilder() (to get a valid entry point. Beside that I also had to do some renaming of the function attributes, e.g. [FunctionName('foo')] => [Function('foo')]. Thanks again!